# PHPUnit_Selenium: Don't throw exceptions if element not found?

Tags: php, testing, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I am using the `PHPUnit_Selenium` extension and encounter some unwanted behaviour if an element does not exist:

**Selenium Test Case:**

```php
$this->type('id=search', $searchTerm);
```

**Test Output:**

> RuntimeException: Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 'http:
>   //localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/': ERROR: Element id=search not
>    found

So, I get an **error** but I would like to convert it to a **failure** instead

I considered this:

```php
try {
    $this->type('id=search', $searchTerm);
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {
    $this->fail($e->getMessage());
}
```

But I don't really want to convert all runtime exceptions to failures and don't see a clean way to distinguish them.

An additional assertion would be great but I can't find one that fits my need. Something like:

```php
$this->assertLocatorExists('id=search'); // ???
$this->type('id=search', $searchTerm);
```

Am I missing something? Or is there another method that I did not think about?

**Used versions:**

- PHPUnit 3.7.14
- PHPUnit_Selenium 1.2.12
- Selenium Server 2.30.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For test cases based on [`SeleniumTestCase`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php), I found the following methods to be useful:

```
getCssCount($cssSelector)
getXpathCount($xpath)
assertCssCount($cssSelector, $expectedCount)
assertXpathCount($xpath, $expectedCount)
```

For test cases based on [`Selenium2TestCase`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php) the solution suggested by [@Farlan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15138813/664108) should work, the following methods retrieve an element and throw an exception if no element was found:

```
byCssSelector($value)
byClassName($value)
byId($value)
byName($value)
byXPath($value)
```

In my case the tests descend from `SeleniumTestCase`, so the solution for the example in the question was:

```
$this->assertCssCount('#search', 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not do something like this:

$element = $this->byId('search');

//from https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php

In java (sorry, I use Selenium in Java) this would throw an exception if the element with id search is not found.  I would check the documentation to see if it is the same behavior in php.  Otherwise you can try to see if the $element is valid, eg: is_null($element)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could check the exception message text in the catch block, and re-throw it if it doesn't match `Element id=search not found` (or a suitable regex).

```
try {
    $this->type('id=search', $searchTerm);
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {
    $msg = $e->getMessage();
    if(!preg_match('/Element id=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]+ not found/',$msg)) {
        throw new RuntimeException($msg);
    }
    $this->fail($msg);
}
```

Not ideal, but it would do the trick.

I guess this demonstrates why one should write custom exception classes rather than re-using standard ones.

Or since it's open source, you could, of course, always modify the phpunit Selenium extension to give it a custom exception class.